# Print element of list inside list in one line statement

Tags: python

Given this list: `list = [[1,'USA'],[2,'UK'],[3,'JAPAN']]`

Is there a way of print the Countries name in one line? I've tried several variations of

```
print (country[1] for country in list)
```

but all I get is some kind of `<generator object <genexpr> at xxxxxx`. I'm sorry if it's already been answered, but I checked at least a dozen questions prior to posting this one.

Comment: String object has a "join" method to join multiple strings together to one string with e. g. a space (or anything else) between them. You can then print the result string.

Comment: @MichaelButscher ok... the element I want to print in this example happens to be a string, but it could be country[0], which is an integer. Anyway, how would that fit in an one line print + for expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, which by default will be printed with spaces in between. You can use the unpacking operator `*` to pass the generator expression's values individually:

```py
print(*(country[1] for country in list))
```

Output:

```
USA UK JAPAN
```